# What exact algorithm and parameters reproduce L-system plant growth figure in Algorithmic Beauty of Plants

Tags: algorithm

I am interested in duplicating a figure (shown below, ch 1 fig 1.21) in the book Algorithmic Beauty of Plants. The book is available here

http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop

[image: Plant generated with an axial L-system]

This image appears in several resources but I have been unable to find the exact rules for the axial system that produced it.

In the book, this figure is presented in the context of L-systems and is referenced in the text as follows.

> Of special interest are methods proposed by Horton [70, 71] and Strahler, 
>   which served as a basis for synthesizing botanical trees [37, 152] (Figure 
>   1.21).

I am unable to find a copy of the PhD thesis (ref 37) and ref 152 does not produce this figure.

Performing a Google image search with this image points to material related to the book, such as slides.

Has anyone here reproduced this figure?

Comment: From the caption text, it seems like Prusinkiewicz's own implementation.

Comment: [ref 152](https://team.inria.fr/virtualplants/files/2013/09/treesviennot.pdf), [ref 70](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/homes/s0451705/horton_1945.pdf)

Comment: Plenty of L-System examples (including trees other plants) are available in [VLab](http://algorithmicbotany.org/virtual_laboratory/) (for mac) and [L-Studio](http://algorithmicbotany.org/virtual_laboratory/) (for PC). You can reproduce the figure by downloading their software and executing its L grammar (which is partially available in the book).

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors?